# Python ffmpeg displaying output

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I want to run command

```
ffmpeg -i movie.mp4 -vf scale=224:224 movie_224.mp4
```

to resize video using python language.

I have code for it:

```
import subprocess
sys_cmd = ["ffmpeg", "-i", "movie.mp4", "-vf", "scale=224:224", movie_224.mp4]
subprocess.check_call(sys_cmd, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

I don't know why I am getting std output even if I have given the argument `subprocess.DEVNULL`.

Comment: Can it be that you are receiving stderr output?

Comment: No. It is regular ffmpeg output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested it. For some reason it goes to stderr output. To fix it run this command

```
subprocess.check_call(sys_cmd, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```